# Why can't I declare a variable in body of a "do while" loop?

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, do-while

I should be able to do this. The "do while" executes the instructions and declares the variable and after compare.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

do{
    int number= rnd.Next();
} while (number != 0)
```

The problem is the scope, for example, i can compile the next code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int number;

do{
     number= rnd.Next();
} while (number != 0)
```

Comment: because `while` is outside `do` scope ... off-topic comment: you should not create new instance of Random inside loop

Comment: Also not a great idea to declare and initialize a Random object inside a loop

Comment: The only use case i find in your code is to make it wait a random amount of time. If that is the case, you could `Thread.Sleep(int milliseconds)` and if would be better resource wise.

Comment: What @Steve and me wrote(about new Random) is written here *[On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#instantiating-the-random-number-generator)* ... and with same seed you will get same sequence which implicates that you may get same value

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `number` does not exist outside of the loop.

Try

```
int number;
Random rnd = new Random()

do{
number= rnd.Next();

}while (number != 0)
```

Comment: Good catch, having the random number generator initialize at each loop iteration was bad code.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way the language works - variables declared inside the `do` block are not accessible outside that block (even in the `while` clause).  It has nothing to do with "when" the variables are declared (in terms of when code is executed). Otherwise, this would be legal, too:

```
do {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int number= rnd.Next();

} while (number != 0)

Console.Writeline(number);  // accessing number outside the loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the number outside the do scope like this:

```
int number;

do{

    Random rnd = new Random();
    number= rnd.Next();

} while (number != 0)
```

Comment: As others have stated, initializing `Random` outside the `do while`would be better

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing curly brackets constitute a scope.You can access a variable declared in a scope within that scope not outside it.
In your case,the while loop is outside the closing curly brackets,so it is outside the scope of 'do'.That's why you can't access the variable from while loop.You have to first declare the variable before the do while loop.